# django login not showing error message

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a regular django login page but for some reason if I enter the wrong login information it's not showing the error messages and it just refreshing the page. Any ideas?

**login.html**

```
{% if form.errors %}
            <p>Your username and password didn't match, please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

        <form method="post" action=".">
            <p>
                <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
                {{ form.username }}
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
                {{ form.password }}
            </p>
            {% if next %}
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
            {% else %}
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/portal/" />
            {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </form>
```

Comment: remove the dot from the action

Comment: can you post the view code for login?

Comment: I removed the "." and same result

Comment: There is no view code that I built. I using the one the comes with django "from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views".

Comment: Are you seeing the information you entered when the page loads up after submitting the action? If not, you may be re-creating the form object.

Answer (score 3):

It could be possible that your creating a new `form`, replacing the form which contains the `form.errors` and returning it to the template. If `form.is_valid():` is not `True` then it looks for the next logical return. It may be possible that you are creating a new `form` right before you return to the template.

**EDIT:**

If you are using the django.contrib.auth.views.login then the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) says that you should specify the `action` in the form and assign it to

`{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}`.

You should change your `form` to

`<form method="POST" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">` also use the use 
the `{% csrf_token %}` after the `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you still wondering like me, thanks to [Django login not showing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823551/django-login-not-showing-errors)   , errors are raised in the general `clean()` method and are displayed in the template via `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`.

Try the below code in your form.

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
   {{error}}
{% endfor %}
```