# Django login not showing errors

Tags: django, authentication

I know there are multiple questions like this around, but none of them contain a clear answer. I am using the default authentication from Django, but have trouble displaying something like 'Your username/password combination is incorrect'. Is it possible to fix this without making a custom view function?

My urls.py looks like this:

```
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'},
    name='mysite_login')
```

Then my login.html has the following code:

```
{% block content %}
<section class="content">
  <div class="container block">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
            <form action="{% url 'mysite_login' %}" class="form-control" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% for field in form %}
                <p>
                  {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                  {{ field|addcss:'form-control' }}
                  {% if field.help_text %}
                    <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                  {% endfor %}
                </p>
              {% endfor %}
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>

              <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"><br>

            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </section>
{% endblock %}
```

So this all works, except for displaying the error messages. I've seen answers where you can write a custom view function and form to fix this, but I assume it should be also possible while using the build-in login functionality right? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [built-in login form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L152) doesn't display errors at an individual field level; it's a security risk to say that just the password is wrong, because it confirms the existence of a particular username. So the errors are raised in the general `clean()` method and are displayed in the template via `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!